# Why is Mathematica dying?

Tags: kernel, crash

Example:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[mat[[1]]]-1, i++,
If[i == 1, mat = Append[mat, mat[[i]]/mat[[i]][[i]]],
mat = Append[mat, mat[[i]] - (mat[[1]]/mat[[1]][[1]])*mat[[i]][[1]]]
]
]
```

where's mat - matrix 4x5. 
If I change

```
  i <= Length[mat[[1]]]-1 -> i <= Length[mat]
```

Mathematica's literaly dying and cannot evaluate this cell.

Comment: See my answer below for why your code runs indefinitely. I have to ask though, what operation are you trying to perform on your matrix? It seems likely that there's a more Mathematica-esque way to do it.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli I write code for Gaussian elimination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because your loop grows the size of your matrix, and therefore `Length[mat]` increases, and thus the loop never terminates!

It appears that the first index of your matrix doesn't change too much (I've not tried to unravel your `If`), and therefore the loop does terminate before `Length[mat[[1]]]` increases too much.

Here's a MWE that demonstrates that you can (either deliberately or in your case accidentally) change the *test* inside the `For` loop:

```
imax = 10;

For[i = 1, i < imax, i += 2,
 imax = imax + 1;
 Print["{i,imax} = " <> ToString[{i, imax}]];
]
```

> {i,imax} = {1, 11}
>
> {i,imax} = {3, 12}
>
> ...
>
> {i,imax} = {17, 19}

Although initially the loop should have only incremented up to `i=10`, because `imax` is changes the loop continues further than naively expected.